# How to specify more than 1 backref

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a 3 tables: users, posts and comments. I'm trying to get username of comment author.

This is my models.py:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    #i'm trying to:
    comment_author = db.relationship('Comment', backref='comment_author_username', lazy='dynamic')
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
#im trying to do:
    #comment_author_username = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('users.username'))
```

but getting an error:

```
AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.comments - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

If i'm using in template {{comment.author_id}} it works properly(shows comment author id), but {{comment.author_id.username}} shows nothing. How i can get comment author username?

Comment: You naming is strange a bit, but if yo want to show a username of a Comment instance, use `{{comment.comment_author_username.username}}`.

Comment: @van I'm just created new table and specify backrefs here, so thank you for helpng!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making TWO relation from table `User` (`comments`, `comment_author`) to table `Comment` (That basically they are the same).

The `author_id` in table `Post` has a `db.ForeignKey('users.id')` but there is no refer to table `Post` in your `User` table.

Basically what you want is, There are some posts that they have their own author, and for each post there are some comments that they have also their authors. The relation between your `Post` and `User` is **One-To-Many** and the relation between your `Post` and `Comment` is also **One-To-Many**. The Relation between `Comment` and `User` is **One-To-Many**. By [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html), Your Tables will be like below:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='poster', lazy='dynamic')
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='commenter', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='comment_on_post', lazy='dynamic')

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```

and for adding data, you can do like:

```
s = db.session

user = User(username='Alex')
post = Post(title='First try', body='This is my first try!')
comment = Comment(body='This is a useful post!')

user.posts.append(post)
user.comments.append(comment)
post.comments.append(comment)

s.add(user)
s.add(post)
s.add(comment)

s.commit()
s.close()
```

and for retrieve data:

```
s = db.session
comments = models.Comment.query.all()
for c in comments:
    print c.user_id
s.close()
```